# Autodesk Forge - 504 Gateway Timeout when uploading file as chunks to BIM 360 storage in Node JS

Tags: node.js, upload, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, resumable

I'm getting a 504 Gateway Timeout when I try to upload a large file in "chunks" using the `PUT` object resumable API endpoint in Autodesk forge.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/

My console log output is below, showing the 504 response, along with the PUT request I send.

I've tried various methods, both using the functions in the `forge-apis` SDK in Node, (eg `uploadChunk` method from `ObjectsAPI`) and also written various functions using `request`, `request-promise-native`, to check if using await/async, promises vs callbacks can help solve the problem.

In all cases, I get the same response - a long pause in the log and then a 504 Gateway Timeout - which appears to be coming from the Forge end.

For context, my Node JS application sits on Heroku, and is triggered from a python script running locally on the client - so Heroku is the 'middleman' - authentication is passed from client-side via python to the node app and then passed on to Forge to authenticate. Other operations in the flow are successful so I'm confident authentication is working correctly.

Can anyone see anything from my logs below that could be causing the problem? Anybody else had similar 504 issues with chunked uploads of large files? (~130MB in this case)

The first log shows my console log output - I'm sending 5mb chunks at 1-second intervals, and sending the chunk as a Buffer object (bytes) sliced to match the Content-Range

```
2020-06-22T10:42:33.389835+00:00 app[web.1]: Ready to upload chunk...
2020-06-22T10:42:33.389896+00:00 app[web.1]: simulating waiting for 1000 milliseconds
2020-06-22T10:42:34.391034+00:00 app[web.1]: done waiting
2020-06-22T10:42:34.392893+00:00 app[web.1]: contentRange bytes 129999974-130056191/130056192
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393393+00:00 app[web.1]: requestParams {
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393394+00:00 app[web.1]: headers: {
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393395+00:00 app[web.1]: Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIxxxxxxxxx',
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393396+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393396+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Content-Range': 'bytes 129999974-130056191/130056192',
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393397+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Content-Length': '130056192',
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393397+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Session-Id': '-75601742'
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393397+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393398+00:00 app[web.1]: uri: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/1fad0fad-601b-41b8-bce4-c88edbb353ec.rvt/resumable',
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393399+00:00 app[web.1]: url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/1fad0fad-601b-41b8-bce4-c88edbb353ec.rvt/resumable',
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393399+00:00 app[web.1]: method: 'PUT',
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393400+00:00 app[web.1]: body: <Buffer 6b b1 b4 e4 d7 f5 1e 59 a0 07 0c db 68 7d 9e 98 75 8e 5f fc e8 0c e3 78 a0 9c b9 59 3f e9 0f 28 e5 5a f0 eb 75 7b 68 16 3d 4c c1 ca 20 7a ba 67 f0 69 ... 56167 more bytes>,
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393400+00:00 app[web.1]: resolveWithFullResponse: true
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393400+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-22T10:42:34.393466+00:00 app[web.1]: Ready to upload chunk...
```

The response comes back like this for each chunk:

```
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443453+00:00 app[web.1]: Uploading 504 > GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443834+00:00 app[web.1]: err:  null
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443969+00:00 app[web.1]: res:  {
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443969+00:00 app[web.1]: ----"statusCode": 504,
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443970+00:00 app[web.1]: ----"body": "",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443970+00:00 app[web.1]: ----"headers": {
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443971+00:00 app[web.1]: --------"content-length": "0",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443971+00:00 app[web.1]: --------"connection": "Close"
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443971+00:00 app[web.1]: ----},
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443972+00:00 app[web.1]: ----"request": {
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443972+00:00 app[web.1]: --------"uri": {
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443973+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"protocol": "https:",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443973+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"slashes": true,
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443973+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"auth": null,
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443974+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"host": "developer.api.autodesk.com",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443974+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"port": 443,
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443974+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"hostname": "developer.api.autodesk.com",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443974+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"hash": null,
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443975+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"search": null,
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443975+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"query": null,
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443975+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"pathname": "/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/1fad0fad-601b-41b8-bce4-c88edbb353ec.rvt/resumable",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443976+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"path": "/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/1fad0fad-601b-41b8-bce4-c88edbb353ec.rvt/resumable",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443976+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/1fad0fad-601b-41b8-bce4-c88edbb353ec.rvt/resumable"
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443977+00:00 app[web.1]: --------},
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443977+00:00 app[web.1]: --------"method": "PUT",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443977+00:00 app[web.1]: --------"headers": {
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443978+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443978+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443978+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"Content-Range": "bytes 129999974-130056191/130056192",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443978+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"Content-Length": "130056192",
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443979+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------"Session-Id": "-75601742"
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443979+00:00 app[web.1]: --------}
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443979+00:00 app[web.1]: ----}
2020-06-22T10:43:34.443979+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my colleague [Luis Felipe Paris](https://www.linkedin.com/in/lfparis/)  - we managed to resolve the problem, after looking at `forge-server-utils` as per Petr's  advice.

By changing our `uploadChunk` function to use the module `axios` instead of `request` or `request-promise` - we found the 504 timeout error disappeared.

We were using the npm module `request` and `request-promise` (even though legacy / deprecated these days) as it supports piping streams from one place to another, and this was working with all other requests we were doing, *except* uploading a 'resumable' file in separate chunks.

We had to convert the file payload we were sending from a `Buffer` object to an `ArrayBuffer`, and slice it correctly to match the `Content-Range` of each chunk.

Some of the older forge examples use `request` - so I guess this might be useful for other users - if `request` gives you problems, try `axios`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: when using the resumable upload feature, make sure that the `Content-Length` request header specifies the length of *just the chunk* you're sending, not the entire size of the uploaded file.

The Forge APIs do have some rate throttling but in that case you should probably get a 4xx status code, not 504.

Can you try a couple of things for us?

- upload the file using this Node.js library: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-server-utils
- upload the file using this Visual Studio Code extension (using the same Node.js library under the hood): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools
- upload your file from your application locally instead of from Heroku (just to rule out that it's some networking issue between Heroku and Forge servers)

And if you're still unable to upload the file, could you please share it with us (confidentially) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`? We would be happy to investigate it on our end.

Comment: Hi Petr, I'm glad and honoured to have your help! You may remember this from the Forge Accelerator London - we are working on transferring files from BIM360 Teams to BIM 360 Docs... our current challenge is to handle the CompositeDesign files  - which are essentially Revit host files which contained linked rvt files, and appear as .zip when we migrate them using our transfer app.

Comment: Our current challenge is to handle the CompositeDesign files  - which are essentially Revit host files which contained linked rvt files, and appear as .zip in 360 Docs when we migrate them using our transfer app. 

Currently our node app is unzipping the file, and then uploading the unzipped .rvt file to BIM360, and creating a new 'version' of the corresponding file - so it's slightly more tricky than just uploading a file by itself...

Comment: We do get the same 504 error when we test locally, without heroku (we also thought it might be something to do with Heroku talking to Forge)

I've been looking at the forge-server-utils methods - they seem to be sending the same request information etc... 

Same 504 occurs with several different files, so we are pretty sure its not a problem with the specific file

Does any of that info shed any more light?

Comment: Hi Ed, yeah I remember :) The issue you're seeing is strange. I remember uploading files over 100MB without any problems. Have you tried uploading the file with the vscode extension? It uses the resumable upload by default, so just to rule out any potential issues in the uploading logic. And have you tried smaller chunk sizes?

Comment: Hi Petr, sure, we will try with the vscode extension to try to debug the steps.. currently our chunk size is 5MB so I think should be small enough? (2MB is the minimum if I recall correctly)

Meanwhile if you can think of any other reason why we might get a 504, let me know - it's as if the Forge server does not answer, perhaps we are missing something in the request? (you can see what we are sending in my first screenshot)

Comment: I'll ping the engineering team. I can't think of any other reason why the server would keep returning a 504. Yep, that's why I wanted to check some of the existing solutions with the resumable upload, to make sure that it's not some missing configuration on the client side (causing the Forge servers to stall instead of returning a proper error code).

Comment: Ed, so the stalling seems to be related to the way you're setting the `Content-Length` header. Instead of specifying the size of the individual chunk, your code seems to be setting the header to the entire 130MB, which makes the Forge servers wait for the rest of the data after the 5MB you actually send.

Comment: Hi Petr @petr-broz, thanks for the update - I saw it after posting the answer below... we did also try setting the `Content-Length` in the header to match the chunk length - with the same 504 error.. moving from `request` to `axios` seems to resolve it... not sure exactly why though!