# BIM Model Performance in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, bim

I did an experiment to compare the loading performance of different BIM models in Autodesk Forge Viewer on the same machine. The duration is measured until PROGRESS_UPDATE_EVENT (*state=2 and percentage=100*).

The loading time is significantly longer of model 1 and 3. I am wondering the performance is subject to the geometry size. May I know any ways to reduce the geometry size in Revit model?

[image: BIM Models Comparison Table]

Comment: Are you using SVF or SVF2?  If you are using SVF, you may try with SVF2 and see if it helps reduce loading time. 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format

Comment: Using SVF2, the performance is better but we encounter another issue when the file size is very big (> 3GB). Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513049/autodesk-forge-504-gateway-timeout-when-uploading-file-as-chunks-to-bim-360-st/67344730#67344730

Comment: Does the issue of uploading in chunk on the other stackoverflow post does not happen when using SVF2, and still exist?  If so, we will need to follow up and investigate.  The intention of SVF2 is to improve performance. If there is anything which does not work with SVF2 but works with SVF, we would like to know.

Comment: The performance issue was tackled by SVF2. Regarding the uploading issue, we developed a program to address it. To be honest, it needs a rather high technical skill to develop the program in order to upload the file size > 3GB. Not user friendly.